# Fast memoization with tuples

Tags: c#, tuples, memoization

I want to use memoization to speed up code looking similar to (only a small number of possible values of arguments are ever called):

```
double MyFun(double a,double b,int c,char d)
{
    double a = cpu_intensive_pure_function_1(a,c,d);
    double b = cpu_intensive_pure_function_2(b,c,d);
    return a+b;
}
```

One possibility is to wrap args into a Tuple object and use Dictionary (new versions of Dotnet have hashing of tuples done for you)

```
Dictionary<Tuple<double,double,int,char>,double> MyFunCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<double,double,int,char>,double> ();
double MyFun(double a,double b,int c,char d)
{
    var tmp = Tuple<double,double,int,char>(a,b,c,d);
    if(MyFunCache.ContainsKey(tmp))
    {
         return MyFunCache[tmp];
    }

    double a = cpu_intensive_pure_function_1(a,c,d);
    double b = cpu_intensive_pure_function_2(b,c,d);
    return a+b;
}
```

But this requires creating an Tuple object every time function is called which seems wasteful, isn't there some better way? Something holding the arguments already?

Comment: I believe that you are already using a pretty efficient (and readable) way. Allocating & comparing tuples should have a negligible performance impact, compared to the "CPU-intensive function".

Comment: @TripleAccretion While "caching" is the valid general term, the special case for pure functions described in this question is usually called ["memoization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Also, the implementation of `Tuple` comparision should already be dealing with hash collisions itself, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I see, that's my mistake.

Comment: If you use `ValueTuple` then you won't take the hit of a memory allocation.

Comment: Another thing: It really helps to profile the affected function, to see whether some operation has a measurable performance impact. Only if this impact is high, optimization may be needed.

Comment: With your current implementation, `MyFun(1.0,2.0,3,4.0)`, `MyFun(5.0,2.0,3,4.0)` will compute `cpu_intensive_pure_function_2(2.0,3,4.0)` twice, separately. If you separately memoized the two individual intensive calls you might achieve better savings. Also, no thread safety concerns?

Comment: The term is **memoization**, not _memorization_.

Comment: @JanWichelmann "CPU-intensive function" is called once, cache is checked millions of times. Small improvements on things that are called a lot of times can still be quite important.

Comment: @Radost Alright, that wasn't clear from the question. I agree, that this may have a significant impact then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ValueTuple` instead. Also, remember to update the cache once you've got the computed value:

```
Dictionary<(double,double,int,char) ,double> MyFunCache = new Dictionary<(double,double,int,char) ,double> ();
double MyFun(double a,double b,int c,char d)
{
    var key = (a,b,c,d);
    if(MyFunCache.TryGetValue(key, out var cachedResult))
    {
         return cachedResult;
    }

    double a = cpu_intensive_pure_function_1(a,c,d);
    double b = cpu_intensive_pure_function_2(b,c,d);

    MyFunCache.Add(key, a+ b);
    return a+b;
}
```